# Можно ли настроить откат AUTO_INCREMENT полей при отмене транзакции?

Tags: mysql

Заметил в mysql, при откате транзакции ROLLBACK, операций INSERT INTO AUTO_INCREMENT не откатывается. Тип таблицы innoBD.

Проблема в том что нужно что бы были одинаковые id, так как в дальнейшем идет выборка связкой таблиц по id.

Можно ил как то настроить откат AUTO_INCREMENT или надо добавлять новый столбец в контролировать целостность id?

Comment: Вообще по хорошему вы должны вставить в первую таблицу, а во второй автоинкремента быть не должно. При вставке во вторую используете функцию `last_insert_id()`

Answer (score 2):

Документация (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html) говорит следующее:

> “Lost” auto-increment values and sequence gaps
>
> In all lock modes (0, 1, and 2), if a transaction that generated auto-increment values rolls back, those auto-increment values are “lost”. Once a value is generated for an auto-increment column, it cannot be rolled back, whether or not the “INSERT-like” statement is completed, and whether or not the containing transaction is rolled back. **Such lost values are not reused.** Thus, there may be gaps in the values stored in an AUTO_INCREMENT column of a table.

Так что увы...

Answer (score 2):

Значения автоинкрементных полей, (а также самостоятельные sequence generators там где они реальзованы) существуют вне транзакций. В этом есть своя мудрость. Иначе было бы сложно избежать повторов в конкурирующих транзакциях.

Как справедливо заметил Mike,  вам нужен только один автоинкремент. Сначала вставили в таблицу с автоинкрементом, затем ссылаетесь на значение из last_insert_id() во всех остальных местах.

Answer (score 1):

Вы оставляете AI в одной таблице (назовем её "Главной" с точки зрения бизнес-логики), а для второй таблицы лучше использовать вставку с использованием foreign key. Это решит непосредственно задачу связки таблиц для выборки.
В любом случае нельзя использовать два AI в разных таблицах для задач связанности данных - это архитектурно неверный путь.